# MySql - join troubles

Tags: mysql

I have two tables : `tracklist(trackid artist event date)` and `radded(trackid, user)` with relation 1 to n (trackid are the keys on each table).

I would like to return the whole tracklist table, by adding a new field called `exist` that should be 1 or 0 if a user (passed trought the query) exist on the radded table for the related trackid for each row.

Example :

**tracklist**

```
*trackid artist event date*
123      art1   eve1  date1
321      art2   eve2  date2
456      art3   eve3  date3
298      art4   eve4  date4
565      art5   eve5  date5
```

**radded**

```
trackid user
123     luigi
123     mario
321     luigi
298     mario
298     antonio
```

if i use the *luigi* as user, the output must be :

```
123 art1 eve1 date1 1
321 art2 eve2 date2 1
456 art3 eve3 date3 0
298 art4 eve4 date4 0
565 art5 eve5 date5 0
```

How can I do this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from `tracklist` to `radded where user="luigi"`. This will get each line from `tracklist` exactly one time, and will put the `username` if it exists, or `NULL` if no appropriate username was found.

Then convert the username to `1`, or the `NULL` to `0` and rename the column as `exist`.

```
SELECT t.trackid, t.artist, t.event, t.date, IF(r.user IS NULL, 0, 1) AS exist
FROM tracklist t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * from radded where user = "luigi") r
ON t.trackid = r.trackid
```

Comment: this is exactly what i've done before. But this unfortunatly doesnt return "0" if the trackid-user dont exist on radded...

Comment: @markzzz: I'm sorry, you're right. I updated the answer, this should work. Uses a subquery to get only the luigi-lines.

Comment: Yeah in fact this query rock as the Andriy M one! Thanks

Comment: Andriy's is the same as knittl: it will join the entire two tables. knittl will display one row for each result, Andriy groups them all and uses the MAX to display one if atleast one row in the group containts the one. Both work, but do an entire table scan of radded. If `radded` becomes huge, it could become slow. Do an `EXPLAIN` ;)

Comment: @Konerak: Agree on using `EXPLAIN`. On the surface, it seems like both your solution and knittl's should be optimised into the same execution plan (which should probably be better than the one for my solution). But I don't have MySQL to verify that.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
   SELECT tl.trackid, artist, event, date,
          (r.user is not null) as exists
     FROM tracklist tl
LEFT JOIN radded r
       ON tl.trackid = r.trackid
      AND r.user = 'luigi'
```

result should be:

```
123 art1 eve1 date1 1
321 art1 eve1 date1 1
456 art1 eve1 date1 0
298 art1 eve1 date1 0
565 art1 eve1 date1 0
```

(edited to only get a single row for each track)

also make sure to have an index covering `radded(trackid, user)`, `radded(user)`, `tracklist(trackid)` and `radded(trackid)`

Comment: yeah, but in fact i want each row for each trackid. And i can't apply group by or distinct on this query....

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  t.trackid,
  t.artist,
  t.event,
  t.date,
  MAX(CASE r.user WHEN 'luigi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag
FROM tracklist t
  LEFT JOIN radded r ON t.trackid = r.trackid
GROUP BY
  t.trackid,
  t.artist,
  t.event,
  t.date
```

---

**EDIT:** some explanation on how it works.

Here's a similar script that doesn't use grouping:

```
SELECT
  t.trackid,
  t.artist,
  t.event,
  t.date,
  CASE r.user WHEN 'luigi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
FROM tracklist t
  LEFT JOIN radded r ON t.trackid = r.trackid
```

Its output would be:

```
trackid artist event date  flag
------- ------ ----- ----  ----
123     art1   eve1  date1 1
123     art1   eve1  date1 0
321     art2   eve2  date2 1
456     art3   eve3  date3 0
298     art4   eve4  date4 0
298     art4   eve4  date4 0
565     art5   eve5  date5 0
```

The `trackids` that are repeated in `radded`, are repeated in this list accordingly. To get rid of duplicates we use GROUP BY. `MAX` is used to get the correct value for `flag`.

Comment: This seems to work! Just the correct syntax is `MAX(CASE r.user WHEN 'djfonplaz' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag`. But I really don't understand how the GROUP BY get the correct value...

Comment: @markzzz: You were right about the correct syntax, fixed that, as well as added some explanation.

Comment: Right! Thanks for the explanation and for the solution:) Could be nice understand which is better between your solution and the Konerak one :)